# Typo3 Neos Redirect to Backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-flow, neoscms

I got question about example site on Typo3 Neos. There is create an account, and i tested it on backend. After submitting, the page return to backend again. But when i try to make a form just like that, the return target is to the route, not to the backend. How can i achieve same return like example?

Even though i already implement same code like example.

```
$uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(); 
$uriBuilder->setRequest($this->request->getParentRequest()); 
$redirectUri = $uriBuilder ->setCreateAbsoluteUri(TRUE)
                           ->uriFor('index', array('username' => $accountIdentifier), 'Login', 'TYPO3.Neos'); 
$this->redirectToUri($redirectUri);
```

Edit: I got an error from 'action', the path he's trying to do is "http://domain/Route/Action/", that should be only "Action". Care to explain?

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

got the answer

```
$this->redirect("youraction");
```

thanks!